Can not save SharePoint list as the Compact view and as standard
I would like to save my SharePoint list with the standard view Compact. Is that possible?
Because i tried by setting it on the compact view but after giving a refresh it goes to
the normal view. I have also tried it to save it as an seperate view and set it as default
but did not work either.
HGow can i make my SharePoint List standard as the compact view ?
Gr .P

As per my test, if I set the list view to compact list, it doesn't go to normal view after a refresh. Change a browser and have a try again.
